# error enabling .MHX mocap addon v 0.6 / 0.7

Tags: add-on, import

I have an error when using io_utils import * but i do not know why ?

[image]

Comment: you are trying to enable .MHX mocap addon?

Comment: from : [space_view3d_mhx_mocap.py](https://developer.blender.org/F16963) ? yep that file needs to be edited/fixed. you have done nothing wrong.

Comment: @zeffii Firstly thanks for your reply. Secondly the error in the space_view3d_mhx_mocap.py is importing io_utils .. I do not know what is the problem with writing 
from io_utils import *

Comment: that's not the only problem, it should be `from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper`, but then you get a new error about restricted context. the addon hasn't been maintained for perhaps a year?..

Comment: yes exactly thats what happens in my case so what should i do to debug this error

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zeffii/a0d6087baec01fcfd615 is my attempt, I don't know if it works because I have no .mhx files to test with. My advice after looking at the addon is to contact the makehuman forum and ask what the blender users there use (there might be other addons for Blender? or newer releases of the addon, -- go to the source. come back when you get a working solution )